# Android tries to download database-created image files

Tags: android, database, image, filestream

I have a script that pulls an image from SQL Server and displays it as a link or on a page.  Works perfectly in a browser and on most mobile devices.  However, when linking directly to the aspx file `<a href="imagehandler.aspx?ImageID=123">link</a>` Android phones download the content but don't recognize the extension as an image, so they just save in the downloaded items folder as an image with an .aspx extension.

How can I cause Android devices to recognize the fileStream as an image instead of an object to be downloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested a simple HTML file in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
This is a test!<br/>
<a href="image.png">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link, the image is displayed in the browser (not downloaded).

The problem must be that `imagehandler.aspx` is not sending an appropriate set of headers. Maybe the script is not setting a `Content-Type` header, or the wrong value, or it is sending `Content-Disposition` attachment.

**EDIT:** This is what the browser app is getting:

[image: Screenshot of Poster]

Comment: Response.ContentType = rsImageData.Item("ImageType")  I am setting the ContentType, which is why most browsers pick it up properly. Try making a hyperlink to this url: http://www.housestat.com/functions/image-display.aspx?ImageType=Property&ImageID=278&Height=600&Width=600

Comment: @Brad: Thanks for the link. I used [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) to examine the response headers and saw that the `Content-Type` is `image/pjpeg; charset=utf-8`. It should be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: @Brad: Another problem is that the resulting image has XHTML at the bottom. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Brad: The `Content-Type` in the response is now `image/jpeg; charset=utf-8`. That's better, but there is still XHTML at the bottom. Most JPEG implementations will ignore it, but some don't. Eventually you will want to get rid of it and make sure that the content type is exactly `image/jpeg` for best compatibility.